# How to name mongodb collections as email names

Tags: mongodb

I want to name mongo collections after email addresses, how can I do this? is there a way to escape . and @ ?

Comment: You need to explain yourself more thoroughly than this. We have no idea what you mean.

Comment: I think he means mongo collections.

Comment: yes I meant collections my bad

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with naming a collection like this. There is a section within the documentation on [collection names](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Restriction-on-Collection-Names) under the general title of limitations:

Basically these:

> In version 2.2, collection names cannot:
>
> - contain the $.
> - be an empty string (i.e. "").

So you seem to be missing the real operators other than the "shorthand" variable notations available under the mongoDb shell:

```js
 db.createCollection("this@my.com")
 db.getCollection("this@my.com").insert({ a: 1 })
 db.getCollection("this@my.com").find()
```

All of those methods are available to drivers as well.

Not sure what the utility of this is, it would seem better to just use the "email" as a key within your documents than create separate collections for these.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command

```
db.runCommand({"create":"a@b.com"});
```

This will create the collection with @ in its name, you'll get following output indicating collection creation.

```
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned '@' is valid, it is not noted in the [collection name restrictions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Restriction-on-Collection-Names).

Some other considerations that you might want to make however:

- The maximum length of a MongoDB collection is 120 bytes (I think it ends up being 116 characters). The maximum length of an email address is 254 characters.
- There is a limit on the maximum number of collections in MongoDB which is based on the size of your namespace file. Using defaults you are essentially limited to 24,000 collections + indexes. See [MongoDB Limits and Thesholds](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limits-and-thresholds) and also this  question [[limits of number of collections in databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858393/limits-of-number-of-collections-in-databases]). Given this limit, even if you were to raise it to the maximum using a larger namespace file, you should consider if it's possible that you might exceed this limit in your particular application
- Querying across collections is not easy, so make sure that you don't have any use cases that might require this

Assuming that you may be building some sort of multi-tenant application, there are a number of resources out there that weigh the various options. Check out [Building Multi-tenant applications on MongoDB](http://support.mongohq.com/use-cases/multi-tenant.html).