# Mongo Collections and Meteor Reactivity

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to decide the best approach for an app I'm working on. In my app each user has a number of custom forms for example X user will have custom forms and Y user will have 5 different forms customized to their needs.

My idea is to create a mongo db collection for each custom form, at the start I wouldn't have to many users I understand the mongo collection limit is set to 24000 (I think not sure). If that's correct I'm ok for now.

But I think this might create issues down the line but also not sure this is the best approach for performance, management and so forth.

The other option is to create one collocation "forms" and add custom data under an object field like so

```
{
    _id: dfdfd34df4efdfdfdf,
    data: {}
}
```

My concern with this is one Meteor reactivity and scale.

First I'm expecting each user to fill out each form at least 30 to 50 times per week, so I'm expecting the collection size to increase very fast. Which makes me question this approach and go with the collection option which breaks down the size.

My second concern or question is well Meteor be able to identify changes in the first level object and second level object. As I need the data to be reactive.

First Level

```
    {
        _id: dfdfd34df4efdfdfdf,
        data: {}
    }
```

Second Level

```
{
   _id: dfdfd34df4efdfdfdf,
   data: {
           Object: 
             {
              name:Y, _id: random id
             }
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is somewhat here [limits of number of collections in databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858393/limits-of-number-of-collections-in-databases)

It's not a yes or no but it's clear regrading the mongo collection limit. As for Meteor reactivity that's another topic.