# How many documents can a single collection have in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I haven't found any information about this.

How many documents can a single collection have in *MongoDB* before it is necessary to use sharding?

Comment: You can find the answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858393/limits-of-number-of-collections-in-databases

Comment: @EldhoNewAge That question is about the number of *collections* in MongoDB, not the number of *documents* within a collection.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no limitation as you can see [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Maximum-Number-of-Documents-in-a-Capped-Collection):

> If you specify a maximum number of documents for a capped collection using the `max` parameter to [create](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/create/#dbcmd.create), the limit must be less than 2^32 documents. If you do not specify a maximum number of documents when creating a capped collection, there is no limit on the number of documents.

Comment: In contrast with @M-A. Fernandes, there is a limitation. But it is not imposed by MongoDB and it's not a fixed number of documents. It may seems very obvious, but correct: the limitations on collection sizes depends on your system capability. How big a collection can be in a single node?

Answer (score 4):

*@M-A.Fernandes* has right.

I can only add [this information](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Maximum-Number-of-Documents-Per-Chunk-to-Migrate):

> Maximum Number of Documents Per Chunk to Migrate
>
> MongoDB cannot move a chunk if the number of documents in the chunk exceeds either 250000 documents or 1.3 times the result of dividing the configured [chunk size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-data-partitioning/#sharding-chunk-size) by the average document size. [`db.collection.stats()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.stats/#db.collection.stats) includes the `avgObjSize` field, which represents the average document size in the collection.